# Spring Connect to Jboss Topic remotely

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jms, spring-integration

I am working on Spring3.1 in a standalone env.

I am trying to consume messages remotely from a jboss4 machine(having Jboss messaging 1.4 as a the jms provider)

After searching in the net I am kind of lost.

what I have done so far is to config my applicationContext with this:

```
<bean id="tgwTopic" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    depends-on="jmsServerManagerImpl">
    <property name="jndiName" value="/topic/feedTopicRealTime" />
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">

        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remove.server.url:1099</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
            <!-- other key=values here -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and this is my java bean:

```
   @Service("TGWMDB")
public class TGWMDB implements MessageListener
{
       @Autowired   Topic tgwTopic;

      public void onMessage(Message message)
      {
      }

}
```

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a message listener container; it's all explained here...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-asynchronousMessageReception